# Multisite getUrl not working on server

Tags: magento-1.8, url, base-url, geturl

I have setup two site on localhost server. It's working fine on local.
But on server it gives wrong url. It give base url on ajax call.

When I use `getBaseUrl` it give right url

Site setup.

```
Website1 :: root
Website2 :: root/test1
```

can any one please guide me on this.

Comment: Not able to understand your question. What Issue are you facing not getting your base url right for each website/store ?

Comment: on general refresh it work. but when i go through ajax and updated html url are from base site not from root/test1